# How to export only my drawingg in Adobe illustrator without the unsed space?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I drew on a 1000 px x 1000 px page. Now there is A LOT OF unused white space in my page. I want to export only the drawing in PNG. How do I crop the drawing from the rest to export it?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually change the artboard size by pressing Shift+O and moving the edges of the artboard.

You can also snap the artboard to the edges of the graphic by going to Object -> Artboards -> Fit to Artwork Bounds.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Save For Web** dialog window **Uncheck** `clip to artboard`.

(If you're using Save for Web).